Do I need to use async if the function returns a promise?
I have this function on a class. It is returning a promise.
static blabla(): Promise <number> {
  return new Promise < number > ((resolve) => {
    resolve(999);
  });
}

This function works fine but I would like to confirm if I need (for good practise) to use async like
static async blabla(): Promise <number>


All functions that are async return promises, but not all functions that return promises are async. You only need that if you await inside it.

VSCode for some reason I don't get recommends doing that but you don't really need to do that, if the function just return a Promise and all the logic is within the function there's no need to mark the function as async since you are not using await.

@jonrsharpe He could write his function like this, right? static async blabla(): Promise<number> {   return 999; }. It's more readable to me.

@MilosStojanovic yeah, but it is probably a trivial example not like it was intended to be written in the nicest way.

@MilosStojanovic they could, yes, but aren't required to. return Promise.resolve(999) would be nearer too. In terms of communicating the return type, the TypeScript annotations achieve that.

I mean, OP is asking for best practice so I guess if you can reduce boilerplate code and not lose on performance, I guess you should use it and be fine with recommending it as good practice.

You don't need to use async if your function already returns a Promise. The async keyword is helpful if you want to use await inside the function, making it easier to work with other promises. Since your function directly returns a Promise, it works fine without async.
You don't need to use the async keyword in JavaScript if your function already returns a Promise.
static blabla(): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve) => {
    resolve(999);
  });
}

Here is an example of how you could utilize asynchronous programming in a more intricate function:
static async example(): Promise<number> {
  const result = await someAsyncFunction(); // Using await for another promise
  return result + 999; // Now it makes sense to use async
}


"async" keyword is used to make a function return a "Promise" implicitly and to allow the use of the "await" keyword inside the function. In your case, since the function already returns a "Promise" explicitly and does not use the "await", using "async" is not necessary.
IF you insist and want to add "async" you could and should refactor the function to be:
static async blabla(): Promise<number> { return 999; }
The function now returns implicitly "Promise" and the async keyword makes this clear.
Both versions are functionality equivalent.
